# AMPScript String Evaluation Incorrect

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

The `concat` string seems to be incorrectly evaluating string in ampscript.

**AMP Script** - Works

```
%%[/* tag - test 1 <div style="display:none"> */

SET @text = "You are <0>amazing</0>."
SET @closeTag = "</0>"
SET @tag = @closeTag
SET @tagLen = LENGTH(@tag)
SET @idxTag = indexOf(@text, @tag)

/* </div> */ 
]%%

Text: %%=TreatAsContent(@text)=%%
Tag: %%=TreatAsContent(@tag)=%%

Tag Start: %%=TreatAsContent(@idxTag)=%%
Tag Len: %%=TreatAsContent(@tagLen)=%%

Text: %%=v(@text)=%%
Tag: %%=v(@tag)=%%

Tag Start: %%=v(@idxTag)=%%
Tag Len: %%=v(@tagLen)=%%
```

Note: I wasn't sure if it should be `TreatAsContent` or `v` so i had both

**Output**

```
Tag Start Pos: 19
Tag Length: 4
```

--

When i try to parameterize the creation of the `closeTag`, there seems to be an issue with how the string is evaluated.

**AMP Script** - Doesn't work.

```
%%[/* tag - test 2 <div style="display:none"> */

SET @i = 0
SET @text = "You are <0>amazing</0>."
SET @closeTag = concat("</", @i, ">")
SET @tag = @closeTag
SET @tagLen = LENGTH(@tag)
SET @idxTag = indexOf(@text, @tag)

/* </div> */ 
]%%

Text: %%=TreatAsContent(@text)=%%
Tag: %%=TreatAsContent(@tag)=%%

Tag Start: %%=TreatAsContent(@idxTag)=%%
Tag Len: %%=TreatAsContent(@tagLen)=%%

Text: %%=v(@text)=%%
Tag: %%=v(@tag)=%%

Tag Start: %%=v(@idxTag)=%%
Tag Len: %%=v(@tagLen)=%%
```

**Output**

```
Tag Start Pos: 0
Tag Length: 0
```

Does anyone know how i can resolve this or what the cause of the issue is? Thank you.

**Issue Summary**: Code Snippets do not work as expected from within Email Editor in Email Studio.

[image]

Comment: You might try using the long-form AMPscript block tags instead of using commented-out HTML AMPscript comments to suppress the code: `<script runat="server" language="ampscript"></script>`

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't change the functionality with it there or not. The div is just to prevent it from showing in the editor but it will still execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though replacing the shorthand opening/closing tags (%%[ ]%%) with the longform does fix the issue for some strange reason.

This is within the context of a Code Snippet block in the email editor.

```
<script runat=server language=ampscript>

SET @i = 0
SET @text = "You are <0>amazing</0>."
SET @closeTag = concat("</", @i, ">")
SET @tag = @closeTag
SET @tagLen = LENGTH(@tag)
SET @idxTag = indexOf(@text, @tag)

</script>

Text: %%=v(@text)=%%<br>
Tag: %%=v(@tag)=%%<br>
<br>
Tag Start: %%=v(@idxTag)=%%<br>
Tag Len: %%=v(@tagLen)=%%<br>
```

Result:

```
Text: You are <0>amazing.
Tag:

Tag Start: 19
Tag Len: 4
```

Comment: That is the first time I see them improving something. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

I took your code that "doesn't work", and it does indeed work.

copy / pasted example two (yes, I made sure) onto a cloudpage, added the AMPscript tags and wrote the output:

```
%%[

SET @i = 0
SET @text = "You are <0>amazing</0>."
SET @closeTag = concat("</", @i, ">")
SET @tag = @closeTag
SET @tagLen = LENGTH(@tag)
SET @idxTag = indexOf(@text, @tag)

]%%
Tag Start Pos:%%=v(@idxTag)=%%
<br>Tag Length: %%=v(@tagLen)=%%
```

result:

```
Tag Start Pos:19
Tag Length: 4
```

I am assuming you did not share the full code and the problem is elsewhere (surrounding loop?)

Comment: That is pretty much the full code. I will update in a moment. I don't have cloud pages, do you have access to Email Studio by any chance to try and generate there?

Comment: Should make no difference in my opinion, it's "pure" ampscript and html, regardless of context. Make sure to put it in an html block and it should work exactly the same.

Comment: Even your snippet does not work in a brand new email (no other code in there). I created a code snippet for the amp script and text component for the output.

Comment: please put all "my" code in an html block / the html section of a free form block and try that.

Comment: Your code worked within an "HTML Content Block" but fails within a "Code Snippet Content Block". The same for my code. I was using Code Snippet Blocks this entire time.

Comment: There should be no difference in processing between the two blocks. If this is truly the case where you used identical environments outside of those two block types, then I would put a note in to support as something is not right. Code Snippet is an HTML Block that does not have a wrapper when called in from AMPscript or Reference blocks.

Comment: So apparently something is definitely wrong with Code Snippet. Appears that having `</` inside of it makes it go crazy. If you change your two vars to concat to separate them out, it resolves the issue: `SET @text = CONCAT("You are <0>amazing<","/0>.")` and `SET @closeTag = concat("<","/", @i, ">")`. It gives the correct value. I have not seen any known issues on this anywhere so its an odd quirk indeed!

Comment: Nice catch. Unfortunately i can't do that since the text is dynamically populated from a DE and the tag <0></0> are part of i18 translations. I used a static string to illustrate the example. I already reached out to SFMC support.

Thank you both.

Comment: Yeah it looks like it is trying to be 'helpful' (much like Outlook....) and is rewriting your code when its processing it - sometimes it randomly moves them out of whatever place they are and shoves them at the very end of your code. Definitely an issue and an inconsistent one as well - I have other places that I have '</' as a string implemented and it works without problem. Very odd...